# A Question regarding Choosing subarray in Python

Tags: python

In the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
a =  np.random.normal(2, 0.1, 10)
c = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [2,4]
print(a[b])
print(c[b])
```

Why print(a[b]) can be executed but an error message is shown for print(c[b])?

Comment: Because `a` is a numpy array and `c` is a list.

Comment: Because a is a numpy-array and c is not. Numpy arrays implement such a feature, lists do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of indexing only works for `numpy.ndarray` and `c` is just a python `list` so you can't index it like `numpy.ndarray`. You can convert it to numpy array first then use your indexing.

```
c = np.array(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, list accepts integer based index.

To execute

```
## Replace print(c[b]) with following line
print(c[b[0]:b[1])
```

Output of the above code

```
[2, 3]
```

The C list is being iterated from index 2 to index 3. As python iterated upto end-1 index.

E.g c[2:4] only index 2 and index 3 will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use bracket on an object like this:

```
a[b]
```

You are calling the function `__getitem__` of the class of the object a with b as the argument. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for more detailed of the function.

Now if `a[b]` does not show an error while `c[b]` raises one this means that the implementation of the method `__getitem__` for the class of `a` is handling the type of `b` and the implementation of this method for the class of `c` does not. This behaviour is exactly the same for every functions, the call is just a bit hidden.